# Reduce number of x axis tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm very inexperienced in writing code, and I've come across a small issue I cannot seem to solve. The x axis on my graph is showing every single x value from my data leaving me with hundreds of labels along my x axis. Is there away to only show 10 values e.g. from 20-30?

My code reads as such:

```
head(CrocDatax[, c("Body_Temperature","Heart_Rate", "Treatment" )])

Treatment<-CrocDatax[,4]

b<-ggplot(data = CrocDatax, aes(x = Body_Temperature, y = Heart_Rate))+ # ggplot comes from the package ggplot2 and is a powerful function for creating amazing figures
  xlab("Body Temperature (°C)")+ # Change the x-axis label
  ylab("Heart Rate (days)")+ # Change the y-axis label
  theme_classic()
b + geom_point(aes(color = Treatment, shape = Treatment))+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue"))
```

I hope the link for the image works.

[image]

Comment: Read about `scale_x_continuous`

Comment: It looks as though your body temperature column is in character or factor format. Try `CrocDatax$Body_Temperature <- as.numeric(as.character(CrocDatax$Body_Temperature))` then re-run your plotting code

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647222/680068

Comment: Thankyou Allan that seems to have fixed it!